# Resolution values in config.lua for applications written for new cell phones.

Tags: lua, coronasdk

We write application with Corona SDK for new cell phones like iPhone4 and SamsungGalaxy2.
What are advanced "width" and "height" values to write in "config.lua" file?

The resolution 320x480 already is old, because all new cell phones have higher one. What is the next size?

Comment: Are you asking us to tell you what the screen resolutions are for various phones?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I tested what are screen sizes of different devices with Corona simulator. I ask about minimal modern "width" and "height" values  to set in "config.lua" file (the most modern phones have larger resolution than 480x320).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `width` and `height` to whatever makes the most sense for your app, then [set the scaling parameter](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2010/11/20/content-scaling-made-easy/) to automatically scale to any device's screen.